# How do I refresh an Android activity that needs to load from the database?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an Android activity that loads information from the database and passes the info to another activity.

Activity two processes the information and updates the database and then restarts activity one this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(TransActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
TransActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

This works fine, but it does not actually load the new information that was updated in the database. How do I start activity one (mainactivity) and have it load the new information that was updated by activity two (TransActivity)?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I need to do this type of thing, I use a `Loader`.  Loaders are a terrific way to set up data for an activity, but they're not very well understood.

You could use a `CursorLoader`, but that requires a `ContentProvider` and I'm betting you don't want to write one of those.

I would write a custom `AsyncTaskLoader` subclass that queries the database and returns a `Cursor`.

Have a look at the docs and sample apps for Loaders to see how it might help you.

Also, instead of restarting the main activity, you should probably look into the `Activity` methods `startActivityForResult()`, `setResult()`, and `onActivityResult()`.  Then your `TransActivity` can "return" to your `MainActivity`.  This is a better flow.

So once you have a `Loader`, your `MainActivity` would call `LoaderManager.createLoader()` to start the loader.

You would invoke your `TransActivity` using `MainActivity.startActivityForResult()`.

Then once your `TransActivity` has updated the database, it would call `setResult()` and `finish()`.

This would invoke the `onActivityResult()` override in your `MainActivity`, where you would call `LoaderManager.restartLoader()` to load the new data.

If you didn't want to use loaders, you could just requery the database in `onActivityResult()` since you know that `TransActivity` is done updating it.

Answer (score 1):

Start your activity two this way

```
Intent i = new Intent (AcitivtyOne.this,Activitytwo.class);
startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_CODE);
```

And having updated information in Activity pass the result back to ActivityOne

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

put data in result intent in any way and receive the data in onActivityResult in ActivityOne and do the rest..

For Reference use this link [Getting a Result from an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)